# Replacing all occurrences in a String

Tags: strings, regex, scala

I have a string like this :

```
val content = "some_text{macro1}another_text{macro2}text"
```

I want to replace the `{macro1}` and `{macro2}` with `macro1` and `macro2`, i.e. just to remove the `{` and `}`.

I wrote some piece of code which works fine, but for me it seems very hard to read:

```
val Pattern = """\{(.*)\}""".r

Pattern.findAllIn(content).matchData.foldLeft(content) ( (newContent: String, current: Regex.Match) => {
     newContent.replace(current.group(0), current.group(1))
   }
)
```

How I can improve this code? Please note: since it's in Scala, I prefer it in the functional way.

Comment: [Related Stack Overflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/978671/1157100)

Comment: Do you want to remove only matched curly braces?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your desire to use the "functional way" is not well-motivated. Why do it "the functional way" when the "other way" is not only easier to read, but also common practice, and well-understood?

```
val stripCurly = "[{}]".r

val replaced = stripCurly.replaceAllIn(a, "")
```

If you want to have forced-matching of the braces consider:

```
val pure = """\{([^}]*)\}""".r
val pured = pure.replaceAllIn(content, "$1")
```

Note the use of the "not a } inside the {}" logic in the regex.

The examples above are running [here in ideone](http://ideone.com/Wuj60Z)

Answer (score 6):

> I know nothing of Scala, and my Regex knowledge is that of the .NET flavor, so please take this with a grain of salt.

In my books, your regex produces only 1 match:

- `{macro1}another_text{macro2}`

You're matching an opening brace and a closing brace, but in-between, *anything goes*, **including** opening and closing braces!

To get 2 matches you could use a lazy/reluctant match for the `.*` part:

```
\{(.*?)\}
```

This produces 2 matches:

- `{macro1}`
- `{macro2}`

---

However an [excluding match](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/91877/23788) is a better option because it doesn't incur backtracking and thus, performs better.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is late, but here's a Scala flavoured way:

Define a function that takes a string as a parameter, filters out all the characters you don't want (in this case `{` and `}`), and then returns a new string:
`val bracketRemover = (str:String) => str.filter(_!='{').filter(_!='}')`

`val targetStr = "This { should }{ not contain { } {brack{ets"`

and then just call the function with your target string:

```
scala> val cleanString = bracketRemover(targetStr)
cleanString: String = This  should  not contain   brackets
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your question, it seems that you should parse the string and remove `{`, `}` from your given string. This simple algorithm just removes the two curly braces from the string.

```
String a="some_text{macro1}another_text{macro2}text";
StringBuilder newString;
for(i=0; i<=a.size; i++){
if(!a.charAtIndex[i].equals({) OR !a.charAtIndex[i].equals(})){
    newString.apend(a.charAtIndex[i]);
 }
}
```

Comment: it's OK, if you feel that i was wrong.